# Firebase namespace not found in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

When I'm trying to build my unity project for WebGL, I'm getting the below error.
I don't get this error when I'm trying to build for Android.

```
The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'FirebaseAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup), Firebase Unity SDK is only support iOS & android.

> Ensure that your Unity project targets the appropriate OS level:
>
> > For iOS — target iOS 8 or later
> >
> > For Android — target API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later